# Can an OpenTelemetry collector use an OpenTelemetry based receiver from another collector?

Tags: open-telemetry, otel

I have a scenario where there's one host with OpenTelemetry collector (primary) that could potentially be allowed to communicate with multiple other collectors (secondary).

Im able to push (exporter) to other collectors but I was curious if there was a way possible for all secondary collectors to add the primary collector as the receiver and get the data. These secondary ones would then export to other vendors/apps as needed. Since the list of secondary collectors are dynamic, we want to avoid a push and rather they be able to receive the data from the primary collector.

I was able to push OpenTelemetry to other collectors, curious if pull based option is a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and it's not only possible but something that we see quite often being used, for example, in Gateway mode. I'm currently working on updating the OpenTelemetry docs with details on it (see preview at https://deploy-preview-2498--opentelemetry.netlify.app/docs/collector/deployment/).

> I was able to push OpenTelemetry to other collectors, curious if pull based option is a possibility.

No.

Comment: Yes , chaining collectors is possible , use appropriate OTEL exporter on your instrumented application or on your intermediate collector for the appropriate OTEL receiver . For implementing tail sampling on open-telemetry a 2-tier collector deployment is recommended in OTEL docs. You can even have multiple exporters on a single collector to export to an appropriate sink (like an APM server , jager etc).